# Azure Python SDK: BlobServiceClient vs. BlobClient?

Tags: python, azure-blob-storage, azure-python-sdk

Most (all?) of the Azure Storage Python SDK examples I've seen demonstrate creating a `BlobServiceClient` in order to then create a `BlobClient` for uploading / downloading blobs ([ref1](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-quickstart-blobs-python#upload-blobs-to-a-container), [ref2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/6771b327bb499c88a40ac059d0c672a0f32130e4/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/samples/blob_samples_common.py#L53), etc.).

Why create a `BlobServiceClient` then a `BlobClient` instead of just directly creating a `BlobClient`?

**Example:**

```
from azure.storage.blob import BlobClient


def create_blob_client(connection_string):
    try:
        blob_client = BlobClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
    except Exception as e:
        logging.error(f"Error creating Blob Service Client: {e}")
    return blob_client

connection_string = os.environ["CONNECTION_STRING"]

blob_client = create_blob_client(connection_string)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're creating a single `BlobClient`, and that's all you need, then just create it directly. If you're creating more than one `BlobClient` using the same credentials and within the same storage account, it's better to create each `BlobClient` from a single `BlobServiceClient` (which has the credentials and storage account).

If you create them from a single `BlobServiceClient`, they all share the same `BlobClientConfiguration`, which is responsible for handling request building and authentication (there's a bit of overhead per `BlobClientConfiguration`, including an authentication token request in some cases that periodically gets refreshed). If you create each `BlobClient` separately, each client will create its own pipeline and authentication cache.

Disclaimer: I have not verified this in the Python Azure SDK code base, but it is true [in the .NET Azure SDK code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/storage/Azure.Storage.Blobs/src/BlobBaseClient.cs#L210), and I'm pretty sure they use the same logic - they do use the same API design.

Comment: Logically put! Thank you.

Answer (score 6):

> Why create a BlobServiceClient then a BlobClient instead of just
> directly creating a BlobClient?

`BlobClient` only allows you to work with blobs so if you want to work with just blobs, you can directly create a BlobClient and work with it. No need for you to create a BlobServiceClient first and then create BlobClient from it.

`BlobServiceClient` comes into picture If you want to perform operations at the blob service level like setting CORS or list blob containers in a storage account. At that time you will need BlobServiceClient.

Answer (score 1):

`BlobServiceClient.get_blob_client` is just a convenience method to easily get a `BlobClient` if you've already created a `BlobServiceClient` and provided the connection information. The [BlobServiceClient API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.blobserviceclient?view=azure-python) says:

> This client provides operations to retrieve and configure the account properties as well as list, create and delete containers within the account. For operations relating to a specific container or blob, clients for those entities can also be retrieved using the get_client functions.

There's nothing wrong with creating a `BlobClient` directly if that's all you need for your use case (e.g. your container is already created). It's likely the docs and examples use the `BlobServiceClient.get_blob_client` method because they are typically end-to-end i.e. create a container, upload a blob, delete container etc.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Coming in as a Python newb, I was never quite sure if I was missing some function that `BlobServiceClient` served.

Comment: Is there any benefit to spawning a `BlobClient` from a `BlobServiceClient` when using the `azure.storage.blob.aio` libraries and `asyncio`?